# Cycle through an array on click

Tags: javascript

I am wondering how to cycle through the values in an array on click?  When the last value of the array is displayed, then the next click should display the first value of the array again.

I think that I am close, however when I get to the last value of the array I have to click twice before it displays the first value again.

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var myArray = ["red", "yellow", "green"];
var myIndex = 1;
var print = document.getElementById('print');

print.innerHTML = myArray[0]; //Print first value of array right away.

function nextElement() {
  if (myIndex < myArray.length) {
     print.innerHTML = myArray[myIndex];
     myIndex++;
  }
  else {
     myIndex = 0;   
  }
};
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<p>The color is <span id="print"></span>.</p> 

<a id="click" href="#" onclick="nextElement();">Click</a>
```

Here's a fiddle if that is helpful:

http://jsfiddle.net/jBJ3B/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the modulo operator like this:

```
function nextElement() {
  print.innerHTML = myArray[myIndex];
  myIndex = (myIndex+1)%(myArray.length);
  }
};
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/jBJ3B/3/

Even more extreme is (as zdyn has written):

```
function nextElement() {
   print.innerHTML = myArray[myIndex++%myArray.length];
};
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/jBJ3B/5/

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I was thrown since myArray.length returns a value of 3, but myArray's last position was 2.  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

As concise as I could get it:

```
function nextElement() {
  print.innerHTML = myArray[myIndex++ % myArray.length]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

var print = document.getElementById('print');

why do you assign a variable to this?
why not just write

> document.getElementById('print').innerHTML = myArray[0]; //Print first value of array right away.
>   document.getElementById('print').style.color = myArray[0]; //Set color of id print.

Comment: Because than I only have to type `document.getElementById('print')` once. I think that assigning it to a variable also caches the reference to the DOM element so it does not have to be looked up agai.